# Analytic form of the normalization constant for Laughlin wavefunction

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-hall-effect

Is there any analytic form of the normalization constant for [Laughlin wavefunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction)

$$\prod_{i < j} (z_i-z_j)^{1/\nu} e^{-\sum_i |z_i|^2/4}$$

where $\nu$ is the filling factor?

Comment: The normalization constant is given on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: As QMechanic told you, the normalization constant is in Wikipedia webpage. I may add that the calculation is pretty simple because Laughlin's wavefunction is a tensor product (properly antisymmetrized) of one-body states which have all the same angular momentum $m$.

Comment: The statement that was on the wikipedia page is incorrect. See this article https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9401163 Steven Simon